# Solving a logic puzzle via Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

So I have a knowledge base of these three tables

```
% order(customer_name, item_name, quantity).
% customer(name, credit_rating).
% item(name, quantity_in_stock).
```

I am supposed to find all valid orders. Valid orders are defined as valid customers with a good credit rating (rating above 500), the item the customer is ordering should exist in the stock and the order quantity must be less than that of the `quantity_in_stock`.

I already figured out for good rating, its just `customer(X, Rating), Rating >=500`. But I cannot figure out how to combine a good customer rating, quantity and then comparing that to the `quantity_in_stock`.

Comment: try modelling joins as you would do in SQL...

Comment: This does not look like a puzzle, but a very ordinary database query.

Comment: Start by describing what you want a little more precisely. *How to combine a good customer rating, quantity...* doesn't seem well-defined. What do you mean by *combine*? If you write it out logically, *such-and-such if this, and that, and the other* then it should be a little clearer what the Prolog should be.